# How to use environment variables in supervisord commands

Tags: python, supervisord, flower

How can I use an environment variable in a supervisord command?
I tried:

`flower --broker=$MYVAR`

but it doesn't work (variable is not expanded), so I tried using an inline python script:

```
command=python -c "import os;os.system('flower --broker={0}'.format(os.environ['MYVAR']))"
```

The command above works, but then I'm unable to terminate the process using `supervisorctl stop` ...I get "stopped" back but the process is actually still running!
How can I solve my issue? (I don't want to put that parameter inline)

Comment: Unless there is a special support builtin in supervisord; you need a shell or other process to expand an environment variable e.g., `command=sh -c 'flower --broker="$MYVAR"'`

Comment: mmm... why if I run "flower --broker=$MYVAR" in the shell it works?!

Comment: because *the shell* expands it

Comment: exactly... so, why is not expanded when supervisord runs my command? :P

Comment: you can run a command without spawning a shell, try `subprocess.call(["echo", "$PATH"])` vs. `subprocess.call("echo $PATH", shell=True)`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the Supervisor docs, you can access environment variables in the command by prefixing ENV_ like: `%(ENV_YOUR_VAR)s`

http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#environment-variables

> String expressions are evaluated against a dictionary containing the keys group_name, host_node_name, process_num, program_name, here (the directory of the supervisord config file), and all supervisord’s environment variables prefixed with ENV_.

However, according to this commit: https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/commit/2d6ca34582a8a07a5dd96ae45ef62cd58a459f4f this feature was added after version 3.2.

Comment: Keep in mind that the latest package in 14.04 is `3.0b2` but this requires `3.2`

Comment: also keep in mind, that vars you specify with `environment=X="value"` are not available in the config file itself as `%(ENV_X)s`, but only for your command, as env var `$X`.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to use a system environment variable in a Supervisor command like this:

`command=php artisan queue:listen --env=%(ENV_APP_ENVIRONMENT)s`

The above command will expand to `command=php artisan queue:listen --env=production` if the `APP_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable is `production`.

Note: In the Supervisor config, you must prefix your system environment variables with `ENV_`, as specified in the documentation [here](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html?highlight=environment#program-x-section-values).